Ramsey type property of the Lipschitz constant
The following problem was proposed by Pietro Majer as an extension of an earlier question of mine on Lipschitz functions.
For $f$ a Lipschitz function on $\mathbb R^n$, we denote by
$$\text{Lip}(f, U) := \sup_{y,z  \in U} \frac{f(y) - f(z)}{|y- z|}$$
the Lipschitz constant of $f$ on the set $U \in \mathbb R^n$.
Question: Suppose $\mathbb R^n = \bigcup_{i=1}^N A_i$ is a partition of $\mathbb R^n$ into finitely many pairwise disjoint measurable sets $A_1, \dots, A_N$. Is it true that
$$\text{Lip}(f, \mathbb R^n) = \max_{1 \leq i \leq N} \text{Lip}(f, A_i)?$$

Ah it's true indeed. The idea is that you can start from a in A, and go to b in B, along a chain a, x, y, z,... b, in such a way that every consecutive pair is in the ckosure of the same set.

And I think even countable coverings should work

@PietroMajer Is the closure of the $A_i$ necessarily nice enough to contain consecutive pairs of the chain? Or maybe I misunderstand the construction.

Try a covering by three closed sets $A, B, C$, and take $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. Now starting from $a$ along the segment $ [a,b]$ you meet a point $x$ which is in $A$ and in some $X\neq A$. If $X=B$ you are done with the chain $(a,x,b)$, if $X=C$, do the same on the segment $[x,b]$ starting from $b$; you'll find a point $y$ in $B$ and in some $Y\neq B$. If $Y=A$, the chain $(a,y,b)$ is ok, if $Y=C$, the chain $(a,x,y,b)$ is ok

Ahh, and I think I see the argument now for countably many sets too - you want to go to the element of $\partial A_1 \cap [a, b]$ that is closest to $b$. And then repeat for the next set $A_2$ you obtain and so on, until the countably many sets are exhausted and you eventually hit $B$, so you are done.

Yes, it also works with no measurability assumption on the $A_i$ and with the constraint that $f$ is Lipschitz weakened to $f$ continuous.

@WillSawin The problem is probably more interesting if the ambient space is not geodesically complete, for example a non complete Riemannian manifold. The Lipschitz constant should be computed using the Riemannian distance in the denominator. I think it should still be true in this case but the argument seems lengthy.

I'd say it holds for X a length metric space. Completeness (in any sense) does not seem necessary

@NateRiver  note that in the argument you wrote  above,  the first sequence converges to some  $c\in [a,b]$,  such that  $A_i\cap[c,b]=\emptyset$ for  infinitely many  indices $i$, but  not necessarily $c=b$, so one needs to start again and again,  a  countable ordinal  of times, before hitting $B$.

Here is a statement in a slightly more general setting (since it is for free).
Let $X$ be a length metric space, $Y$ a metric space, $f:X\to Y$ continuous,    $(A_i)_{i\in \mathbb N}$ a countable covering of $X$,  such  that $f$ is $L$-Lipschitz on each set $A_i$. Then $f$ is $L$-Lipschitz on $X$. In other words $$\text{Lip}(f,X)=\sup_{i\in\mathbb N} \text{Lip}(f,A_i).$$
Rmk. Since $X$ is a length metric space, it is sufficient to assume $[0,1]$ as a domain of $f$. We can also assume $Y:=\mathbb R$: the case of  normed-space valued functions follows from Hahn-Banach by composing with linear functionals. By the Fréchet-Kuratowski embedding this includes the case of general metric space $Y$.
Proof 1.  Consider $$R:=\{(x,y)\in X\times X:  |f(x)-f(y)|\le L|x-y|\}.$$
As a relation on $X$, $R$ is a closed equivalence relation, with at most countably many classes. So by Sierpiński‘s theorem it is trivial, meaning that $f$ is $L$-Lipschitz.
[edit] Also
Proof 2. Let $Z_i$ be the (countable) set of isolated points of $A_i$,   and $Z:=\cup_{i\in\mathbb N}Z_i$. Every $x\in[0,1]\setminus Z$ is an accumulation point for some $A_{i_*}$, therefore $$\displaystyle D_*f(x)\le\liminf_{y\to x\atop y\in A_{i_*}}\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\le L$$
holds for all points but a countable set, which implies (together with the same bound  for $-f$) that $f$ is $L$-Lipschitz.

(transitivity  of the relation   $xRy, yRz  \implies  xRz$ is less obvious  if $x<z<y$ and needs a proof)

Sierpinski’s theorem is very pretty - I am surprised I have not come across it before. By the way, I wonder under what conditions on the $A_i$ the sup is actually achieved by some $A_i$.

If  $X$ is compact and the $A_i$  are open (or more generally if the interior of the $A_i$ still covers X), then yes,  because  the  Lipschitz constant of $f$ can be achieved by  a sequence   $(x_n, y_n) $  with $d(x_n,y_n)\to0$, thus  eventually in the same $A_i$. Outside this case, I guess one can  find  $f$ for which  $ \text{Lip}(f,A_i)<\text{Lip}(f)$ for all $i$
